# I know that the probability of getting any card of the 12 cards is 1/3(4/12), but I don't understand what to do next.

Tags: probability

From a standard deck of 52 cards, the four Aces, four $2$'s, and four $3$'s are drawn, forming a smaller deck of $12$ cards. All $12$ cards are dealt at random to four players, so that each player gets three cards. What is the probability that each player's hand consists of an Ace, a $2$, and a $3$?

Comment: Use combinations to count the number of total hands (from the 12 card deck) and the number of hands that consist of A, 2, 3. This ratio will give you the probability that the first player received the hand you're looking for. Now, with a 9 card deck, how many hands are there? How many hands consist of A, 2, 3? Then do the same for the third person. The fourth person's hand is determined at that point.

Comment: **Please do not discuss this problem! This is an active homework problem.** @As1an Mushro0m: I realize that homework may be challenging. If you wish to receive some help from the staff or other students, I encourage you to use the resources that the online classes provide, such as the Message Board. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the first player.  You choose three cards of the $12$.  How many total hands are there?  How many have $A23$?  That gives you the probability.  Assuming the first player is a success, you have a nine card deck to select the second player's hand from, three of each rank.  The same process applies.  Keep going.

Comment: So, I did 4/12*4/11*4/10+3/9*3/8*3/7+2/6*2/5*2/4 = 1559/9240 Which is wrong

Comment: For the first hand $4^3$ is the number of unordered hands that have $A23$ while $12 \cdot 11 \cdot 10$ is the total number of ordered hands.  You are off by a factor $6$ here.  It should be $\frac{4^3}{12 \choose 3}$  Then you should multiply the hands, not add them, because you need each to have $A23$